# Solidity: populating a struct in a smart contract

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts

I created a struct that stores a few different variables, and I populate it but the string is not stored.
Here is my smart contract:

```
struct voter {
    uint ID;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
}

contract Poll {
    uint public numVoters;

    function AddVoter(string memory _firstName, string memory _lastName) public returns 
    (voter memory)
    {
        numVoters++;
        voter memory _voter = voter(numVoters, _firstName, _lastName);
        _voter.ID = numVoters;
        _voter.firstName = _firstName;
        _voter.lastName = _lastName;
        return _voter;
    }
}
```

When I run a javascript test using truffle:

```
it('Poll 1 : create voter and candidate objects2', async () => {
        
        const JJ = await poll.AddVoter('Jack', 'Jackson', 0, '');
        assert.equal(JJ.firstName, 'Jack');
    });
```

I get this error line:

Contract: BVT
Poll 1 : create voter and candidate objects2:
AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 'Jack'

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. AddVoter receive two parameters, but four were given.
2. You can not use the returned value from a smart contract from an off-chain code...only other smart contracts on the chain can use the returned value. So the alternative is to emit an event. That way, you can access the newly created vote.
   In that case, your contract would look like this:

   ```
   struct voter {
        uint ID;
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
    }

    contract Poll {
        uint public numVoters;

        event VoterAdded(
            voter newVoter
        );

        function AddVoter(string memory _firstName, string memory _lastName) public returns 
        (voter memory)
        {
            numVoters++;
            voter memory _voter = voter(numVoters, _firstName, _lastName);
            _voter.ID = numVoters;
            _voter.firstName = _firstName;
            _voter.lastName = _lastName;
            emit VoterAdded(_voter);
            return _voter;

        }
   }
   ```

And the test code would look like this:

```
it('Poll 1 : create voter and candidate objects2', async () => {  
      const tx = await poll.AddVoter('Jack', 'Jackson');
      const reciept = await tx.wait();
      const [ VoterAdded ] = reciept.events || [];
      const result = [...(VoterAdded.args || [])]; 
      const JJ = result[0];
      assert.equal(JJ.firstName, 'Jack');
   });
```

Note: There are some workaround codes to be compatible with `Typescript,` but it would also run in `Javascript`.